# Stata: reshape long to wide dataset with uneven number of observations

Tags: stata

I am trying to convert a long data set to wide, with uneven number of observations.

The problem preventing me from doing a simple reshape in Stata, is that there may be 2 observations for 1 individual and 3 for another and so forth.

What I want is to reshape to wide. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The "problem" you describe is not in and of itself a problem; there is no requirement for `reshape wide` to have complete data for each individual. Perhaps if you posted a sample of your data, your attempt to use `reshape wide`, and Stata's response, readers could help you identify and correct your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on posing questions that can be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

As @William Lisowski comments, your precise problem is unclear.

Here's proof of concept that unequal numbers of observations are not a problem as such. The consequence is necessarily missing values in some variables.

For almost all Stata purposes the `long` structure is preferable.

```
. input id time y

            id       time          y
  1. 1 1  12
  2. 1 2  23 
  3. 2 1  98
  4. 2 2  76
  5. 2 3  54
  6. end 

. reshape wide y, i(id) j(time) 
(note: j = 1 2 3)

Data                               long   ->   wide
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        5   ->       2
Number of variables                   3   ->       4
j variable (3 values)              time   ->   (dropped)
xij variables:
                                      y   ->   y1 y2 y3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. list  

     +-------------------+
     | id   y1   y2   y3 |
     |-------------------|
  1. |  1   12   23    . |
  2. |  2   98   76   54 |
     +-------------------+
```